# Tally value in dynamically generated textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have input textboxes generated dynamically. I also have a function(split_advance();) that will split a value into the textboxes according to the number of boxes($num_item) generated. What i need to do is tally the amount in the rest of the textboxes if the value of any one is altered so that the overall sum is the same as the entered value. Is this possible with javascript? coz im using php and javascript.Ajax wil also do.

```
 $num_item=mysql_num_rows(some query);
   <td><input type="hidden" name="num" id="num" value="<?php echo $num_item; ?>" /></td>
<?php $j=0; ?>
     for($i=0;$i<$num_item;$i++)
            {
$j++;
<td width="50"><strong id="tot<?php echo $j; ?>"><?php echo $row_item['item_total']; ?></strong></td>

        <td><input type="text" class="vertical" name="advn" id="advn" onblur="split_advance();" value="0" /></td>

        }

function split_advance()
{
    var numr=document.getElementById('num').value
    modal=document.getElementById('advnc').value;
    for(var i=1;i<=numr;i++){
        var a=document.getElementById('tot'+i).innerHTML;
        if(a < modal){
            document.getElementById('advn'+i).value=a;
            modal=modal-a;
        }
        else if(a > modal){
            document.getElementById('advn'+i).value=modal;
            modal=0;
        }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to give more code, so we can give a more accurate answer. And, anything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you want are creating multiple text fields and splitting one value in all of them so the same as your no....

And when one will alter any text field that new value should be divided into all of them and sum of all text areas should be that entered value, am I correct??

Please share your code for split_advance so that we can help...

and it should be called onblur so that you are doing correctly..no need of ajax or anything

just need to modify your split advance function

Comment: now i am bit confused please give little more explanation if possible with 4 text field initial values and if you update anything then newly updated values...so that i can understand it...and please code if possible

Comment: Not exactly when i alter the value in one textbox the others should be altered but the sum should be the same as before ie. modal is the amount to be split that should be fixed the values in the textbox should be increased or decreased according to changes in them but the overall sum should be the same as before. Also i need it to stay within limits each textbox has a diff total generated [item total].

Comment: ok so yeah i get your problem except for this line 

Also i need it to stay within limits each textbox has a diff total generated [item total].

and if you want modified code can u please share split_advance function

Comment: my table is generated as follows i have 3 fields item name, item total, and advance...now i enter an overall advance(modal)..this amount is split into each item generated..supposed i entered an advance of 4000...i have three items with totals of 2200,2000 and 600..now when it splits the first item gets 2200 the balance 1800 falls in the second item and the third is empty...suppose i want to reduce the first item advance to 1500 the rest should be split with the other two but should not exceed their item total...phew!!

Comment: ther is an overall advance and an advance for each item...the overall advance is split into the advance for each item...

Comment: i have tried to find error but i think you code is correct at least i am not able to locate an issue with it..

only fix is
instead of if(a < modal) go for if(a <= modal)

Comment: i dont want u to find an error...im askin if the requirement i said is possible n if so how to do it...

Comment: ya offcourse its possible, and you need to call your split function on blur event of textfields of advance fields..so if anyone is changed a function will get trigered and that will split value based on overall advance and newly entered value and other fields values